# Install Python app dependency without pip install command

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run Python script from C# program. I use official documentation from Microsoft: [Inter-process communication between C# and Python.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/C-and-Python-interprocess-171378ee)I am supposed to deploy this project by making it as `.exe`. When i am exectuing `.exe` file, it's throwing `error: 'No module named numpy/ matplotlib.Suggest me some idea to resolve this issue.`Samples file is given below:

**demo.py**

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure
import scipy
import cv2

'some code using above package'
```

Comment: @L.B question itself is specific to resolve package issue. Not more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install python packages locally w/o root/admin permissions. I tested next code and it works.

```
import pip
import os
import sys 

def pip_install(packages, dir_to_install):
    for package in packages:
        pip.main(['install', '--target={}'.format(dir_to_install), package])

local_repo_path = os.path.abspath('local_repo')
sys.path.append(local_repo_path)
packages_list = ['numpy', 'scikit-image', 'opencv-python']
pip_install(packages_list, local_repo_path)

import numpy as np
from skimage import measure
import scipy

'some code using above package'
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for me. But i have one more question like will your code work for windows environment. Becuase system may be 32 bit/64 bit. So packages should be downloaded accordingly. In the same code, how can i install opencv2.7 version/ opencv3.2?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Windows OS`, but I suppose that pip is crossplatform tool and I believe that behaviour is the same. To chose package version, you can do next `pip install opencv-python==2.7`

Comment: I didn't chek this. So, just add `opencv-python==2.7` and `opencv-python==3` to the `packages_list`. Also note, that version could be different, so please check it.

Comment: BTW, you can also install it from oficial site for example:
`packages_list = ['numpy', 'scikit-image', 'scipy', 'https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.3.0.tar.gz', 'https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.3.0.tar.gz']`
Such links I got from [oficial site](http://opencv.org/).

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to add your local_repo path into search path.